# How to deploy bot to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bots, aws-cli

I am new to AWS stack and wanted to know how to deploy bot to AWS, I do have AWS account, referring to HelloWorld chat bot tutorial [here](https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/hello-world-chatbot.html)

The command mentioned to deploy is

```
claudia create --region us-east-1 --api-module bot
```

but can someone point to steps required to configure AWS before running this step?

I get following JSON on running the above command,

```
{ [CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config]
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
  errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '169.254.169.254',
  port: 80,
  time: Mon Nov 28 2016 12:17:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
  originalError:
   { message: 'Could not load credentials from any providers',
     code: 'CredentialsError',
     errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '169.254.169.254',
     port: 80,
     time: Mon Nov 28 2016 12:17:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time),
     originalError:
      { code: 'ENETUNREACH',
        errno: 'ENETUNREACH',
        syscall: 'connect',
        address: '169.254.169.254',
        port: 80,
        message: 'connect ENETUNREACH 169.254.169.254:80' } } }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can check instructions from https://claudiajs.com/tutorials/installing.html

Add the keys to your `.aws/credentials` file

```
[claudia]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET
```

Set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable to claudia or use the `profile` option when running the command

```
claudia create --region us-east-1 --api-module bot --profile claudia
```

Comment: This problem got solved, however i get following JSON D:\chatbot>claudia create --region us-west-2 --api-module bot
initialising IAM role   iam.createRole  RoleName=helloworld-executor
{ [NetworkingError: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.239.22.207:443]
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 54.239.22.207:443',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '54.239.22.207',
  port: 443,
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: 'iam.amazonaws.com',
  retryable: true,
  time: Mon Nov 28 2016 16:09:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) }